# How to set divider height for childview in expandable listview

Tags: android, user-interface, parent-child

How to set different divider height values for childview and parentview in expandablelistview

Here my code is

Expandablelistview.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

expandable_child.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Main_Navigation" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="#E5E5E5"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#000000" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_two"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Expandable_header.xml

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/fag_dropdown" (image)
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:text="aaaaa"
android:textSize="15sp"

/>
```

border_two.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#A4A4A4"/>
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
```

so,how to set different divider height for header and child

Comment: did u tried expView.setDividerHeight(2);? , plz post ur code

Comment: i was tried,but i need two different divider height for parentview and childview thats my problem

Answer (score -1):

Try this :  `android:dividerHeight="50dp"`

Comment: Willl set height for group and child, op only wanted for child.